# Hiding shared_ptr implementations

Tags: c++, c++11

I have C++ class defined like this :

```
namespace glDetail
{

    class CMesh
    {
    public:
        CMesh(const char* fileName);

         /// some more functions...

         CMesh& operator=(const CMesh& other) = delete;
         CMesh(const CMesh& other) = delete; ///note that assignement operators are disabled ! 
         // That is why I need to use shared_ptrs !
    private:
         /// some member vars...
    };
}

typedef shared_ptr<glDetail::CMesh> Mesh;

shared_ptr CreateMesh(const char* fileName){
    make
}

///main.cpp

int main(int argc, char** args){

     Mesh mesh = CreateMesh("someFileName");
     mesh->Render();

}
```

Would there be a way I could hide this implementation, and Instead of calling CreateXXX call a proper constructor ? (Also calling -> instead of . is confusing...)  Like Mesh mesh = Mesh("someFileName");

Comment: Completely unclear, why you need shared pointers. Did you mean to implement a Singleton?

Comment: No; Mesh is an opengl based class : It's assignement operators are disabled, so if I'd used CMesh, I would have to pass it as pointer, nearly everywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is that only `->` can be overloaded for custom types, not `.`. Overloading `->` is what enables smart-pointer classes to provide simple delegation to member functions of their owned object, i.e. the ability to simply write `mesh->Render()` instead of `(*mesh).Render()`.

The only thing you can do to get some syntactic sugar is "upgrading" your `typedef` to an actual wrapper class which encapsulates the `shared_ptr` and delegates everything to the owned object:

```
class Mesh 
{
    public:
        Mesh(const char* fileName) : ptr(std::make_shared<glDetail::CMesh>(fileName)) {}
        void Render() { ptr->Render(); }
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<glDetail::CMesh> ptr;
};

///main.cpp

int main(int argc, char** args){

     Mesh mesh("someFileName");
     mesh.Render();
}
```

> Also calling -> instead of . is confusing...

Not really. It's a visual indicator for a pointer. I think that's a good thing. In fact, as a C++ programmer, I would be very *confused* if I saw a class like `Mesh` seemingly behaving like a value type that can be created and copied around freely as if it was an `int` or a `std::string`. You should at least consider calling it `MeshWrapper` or `MeshHolder`.

> Like Mesh mesh = Mesh("someFileName");

That looks a lot like Java. In C++, the syntax is simpler (see above). A modern alternative advocated by some C++ experts like Herb Sutter would be:

```
 auto mesh = Mesh { "someFileName" };
```

In fact, I wonder if the desire to not use `->` also comes from a Java background. If so, you should just get used to the C++ pointer syntax. It's a different language, after all.

Comment: 2) By confusing, I meant for the user : he thinks the object he create is an object, but then calls it like a pointer.

Comment: @Coder32: In C++, primitive types become "objects" as well, so a pointer *is* an object. You probably mean objects of custom types. But that's not the point anyway. The point is that for a function like `CreateMesh`, I would *expect* a pointer to be returned. Not because of the "Create" part, but because meshes sound like something which cannot be copied or assigned freely. The more difficult question is which kind of pointer: raw, shared or unique.

Comment: Ok , Thanks . I started another question on this  thread (subject is different); You can help, maybe :) http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101716/node-based-rendering

Comment: Bad design. Bad-bad-bad design! If you must include shared_ptr into your class (as a rule of thumb, DO NOT!), you MUST include an allocator as well. Otherwise you are doing terrible disservice to your users.

Comment: @SergeyA: That's too broad a statement, given that we have no idea how this class is going to be used; in particular, we do not know whether this is library code or application code.

Comment: Exactly. Give that we do not know how the class can be used,we can't limit it users to heap memory allocations. And even application level code can be reused in other parts of the application, provided we are not talking about hello world.

Comment: @SergeyA: That's not what I meant. I meant that we as SO users do not know how the OP uses this class in his project. Not everything is meant for extensibility and reuse. For all we know, this class might just be used in a few places and never require a custom allocator at all. If that's the case, then providing the ability to add one would be a waste of time. You also have to consider that such a `Mesh` class might only be a convenience class and that users may still be able to access the underlying class if they need to.

Comment: I believe, SO should promote good practices, not bad practices. And in particular, providing a class which does memory allocations without providing it with some means to customize those allocations is generally bad. If in a particular case an exception can be made, it can be made. But general advice should follow good practice.

Comment: @SergeyA: *"providing a class which does memory allocations without providing it with some means to customize those allocations is generally bad"* - Which means every class with a private `std::string` or `std::vector` member variable should provide a custom allocation mechanism? Here's another thing: What if I later choose to replace the `shared_ptr` *private implementation detail* of the class with something else, which does not support custom allocation? What if I replace the entire internal `glDetail::CMesh` with something else?

Comment: Yes. Any class with vector inside is better to provide an interface to customize the allocator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way. Do not cohabilitate class with it's memory management strategy. This is a very bad practice. Give your users your CMesh class, and let them do what they want with it. Class should not concern itself with the way it's instances are managed.

Comment: I cannot give my users this CMesh class, because they would have to pass things by pointers everywhere, which is even worst...

Comment: I doubt so. There are very small number of legitimate uses of shared_ptr (99% of all uses I've seen were not justified), and even less so for passing shared_ptrs around. Passing shared_ptr is actually a very bad thing to do, as it is a true performance killer.

Answer (score 1):

You should encapsulate the shared_ptr in another class through a composition pattern. For example:

```
class MMesh {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<glDetail::CMesh> mesh;

public:
    MMesh(const char *fileName) {
        mesh = std::shared_ptr<glDetail::CMesh>(new glDetail::CMesh(fileName));
    }
    glDetail::CMesh * operator -> () const {
        return mesh.get();
    }
};


///main.cpp

int main(int argc, char** args){

     MMesh mesh("someFileName");
     mesh->Render();

}
```

I only wrote one constructor and the operator `->`, I'm pretty sure you will need other constructors and some other methods to correctly use the `shared_ptr`, but you forgot to say how you wanted to use it or why you needed it.